# What stats do mobs have at each dungeon level?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I am playing Dungeons of Dredmor at average difficulty and permadeath enabled but I always died inside level 4/5. So I decided to carefully plan my next moves before trying again.

The first things that I would like to know are:

- Damage per turn
- Type of damage
- Armor / Damage Absorption
- Type of resistance

of each basic mob at the different dungeon levels.

I checked the [wiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Mobs), but these values are not there yet. Any ideas where I can find that information?

Comment: As much as I'm interested in the answers to this question, I can't see how any answer here will stay correct for long, because there's so much patching going on at the moment; tweaking balance will go on a long while after *that*. Also, what should the format be? One comprehensive list, one answer per level, one answer per mob? Maybe we should point to a wiki, or make it CW...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that someone did a great job on Dredmor Wiki. Now the [Monsters](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Monsters) page seems to have all the information a was looking for.